# storing multiple values in same array with same index

Tags: php, arrays

If I want to add multiple values in array having same index in **PHP**, then can it be possible to create this type of an array? For e.g.,

```
fruits[a]="apple";
fruits[a]="banana";
fruits[a]="cherry";
fruits[b]="pineapple";
fruits[b]="grappes";
```

I want array to look like as below:-

```
fruits = {[a]=>"apple",[a]=>"banana",[a]=>"cherry",[b]=>"pineapple",[b]=>"grappes"};
```

Comment: Which language you are using?

Comment: If you are using java, I would suggest you to use `Map` with key and corresponding to that key list of object as a value.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I am using PHP.

Comment: Why is it required ?? Explain more..

Comment: You should use two dimensional array

Comment: you cannot add same data with same key more then once as per my knowledge

Comment: Thanks @Rahul. Can you help me out in one query as well.As I want to pass the same array in Foreach loop with same condition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot define multiple value under same key or index. 
In your case -

```
fruits[a]="apple";
fruits[a]="banana";
```

Here `apple` will be replaced by `banana`.

Instead, you may define array as -

```
fruits[a][] = "apple";
fruits[a][] = "banana";
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: i updated my answer with php code, but i don't code php usually, this might not be the most optimal solution, i tried this code in a php sandbox

```
$subarray1[0] = "apple";
$subarray1[1] = "banana";
$subarray1[2] = "cherry";

$subarray2[0] = "pineapple";
$subarray2[1] = "grappes";

$fruits[0] = $subarray1;
$fruits[1] = $subarray2;

foreach( $fruits as $key => $value ){
    foreach( $value as $key2 => $value2 ){
        echo $key2."\t=>\t".$value2."\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**use implode and explode .**

```
subarray1[0] = "apple"
subarray1[1] = "banana"
subarray1[2] = "cherry"

subarray2[0] = "pineapple"
subarray2[1] = "grappes"
```

**It is store data with ,(comma)**

```
$ar="";
for($i=0;$i<=count(subarray1);$i++)
{
$ar[]=subarray1[$i];
}
$rt=implode(',',$ar);
 echo $rt;
```

**It is Remove ,(comma) form array**

```
$ex=explode(",",$ar);
print_r($ex);
```